# Helm template ternary set operator

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

In Helm `v3` how can use a ternary set operator in a template? I am looking for logic `if Values.global.postgresql.password` is set *(not empty)* use that, else use `Values.default.POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD`. The following is not working:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  postgresql-password: {{ .Values.global.postgresql.password | .Values.default.POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD | b64enc }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgresql-password
type: Opaque
```

Answer (score 0):

> if `x` is set use that, else use `"some-default"`

The Helm (Sprig) [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function does this; `{{ x | default "some-default" }}`, or `{{ default "some-default" x }}`.

```yaml
postgres-password: {{ .Values.global.postgresql.password | default .Values.default.POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD | b64enc }}
```

Comment: What if `x` is true then `y` else `z`?

Comment: First choice would be an ordinary `{{ if }}...{{ else }}...{{ end }}` block, if that's a choice, but if you really need it in a single expression, there's [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary).

Comment: Yeah the literal `ternary` function was what I was looking for, thanks. (e.g. `ternary y z x` or `x | ternary y z`)